# What does !== mean in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I encountered something similar to this in a codebase.

```
if varA !== varB {
   // some code here...
}
```

Is that the same as

```
if varA! == varB  {
   // some code here...
}
```

which means that varA is force unwrapped?

Comment: `!==` is *documented* in the Swift book.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In swift `==` means "Are these objects equal?". While `===` means "Are these objects the same object?".

The first is a value equality check. The second is a pointer equality check.

The negation of these are `!=` and `!==` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, `===` and `!==` are [identity operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html).  They are used to determine if two objects refer to the same object instance.

So in that sample code, the condition is checking if `varA` and `varB` refer (or, rather, don't refer) to the same object instance even though they're different variables.