# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
let bookId = dict["bookId"] as? String ?? ""
    let date = dict["date"] as? String ?? ""
    let xp = dict["xp"] as? Double ?? 0.0

if (bookId !== "summary") {
    hasBooks[bookId] = true
    numCompletedBooks += 1
    totalXp += 10
    if dateNumBooks[date] == nil {
        dateNumBooks[date] = 1
    } else {
        dateNumBooks[date]! += 1
    }
    dateBooks[bookId] = date
} else {
    streak = dict["streak"] as? Int ?? 0
}
```

I get the following error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'` on line  `if (bookId !== "summary") {`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the real code? There s no optional `AnyObject` in the code. Actually you should get ***Binary operator '!==' cannot be applied to two 'String' operands***. The usual value-type *is-not-equal-to* operand is `!=` (one equal sign). And this is Swift: No parentheses around `if` expressions!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if (bookId !== "summary")
```

with

```
if bookId != "summary"
```

it's `!=` not `!==` check [What does !== mean in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233766/what-does-mean-in-swift)